# python plugin IPDB installation

Tags: python

I tried to install ipdb for debugging python, but after I downloaded ipdb0.61 and extracted it, there are only a few .py file. I don't know how to install it? I tried to run setup.py, it did not work. In the folder "IPDB" there are two py files: **main**.py and **init**.py. How should I install it? I know there is another way to do it by the way of easy_instal. However I want to modify it to support python3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

easy_install should be able to install it for you by typing

```
easy_install ipdb
```

If you don't have setup_tools get them from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/

Comment: If you get `Permission denied`, use `sudo`. I am wondering that you were able to install it without sudo.